# Creating UIView with pre-defined size in pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Is it possible to create a custom `UIView` that will be rendered on for example `1500 x 1500 pixels`? I can easily create an image from a `UIView` and save it, my problem starts when I'm using an iPhone 5 and the image I save will be `640 x 640 px` (the `UIView` is a square) because `640 pixel` is the `maximum width` of it's screen resolution. So when I use the same image on a iPhone 6 Plus it will be pixelated because its screen width is `1080 x 1080 px`, therefore I need to create the images that looks good on every screens. How could I manage this? Or how could I make a UIView that will be the same on every device?

In this case the result will be different based on the type of the retina screen:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.fullView.frame;    
newFrame.size.width = 1500;
newFrame.size.height = 1500;
[self.fullView setFrame:newFrame];
```

I have an idea, that I would use if statements to figure out the current device and use different sizes for different devices, but a cleaner solution would be amazing. However I'm not sure that it would be the proper 
logic so I welcome any other solution.

I'm saving the `UIView` as a `UIImage` with   `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);` so the saving method won't decrease the size.

Comment: so you want the image size to be 640x640 on all devices?

Comment: @T_77 No, I want 1500 x 1500.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you should Auto Layout to make the view fit the correct screen size.

Also, if you want to have a specific image for each screen size you should use [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) where you can create an image set with the will load a different image for each device.